# Display only the text items of an SVG file with QT

Tags: c++, qt, qmake, qt5.15, qgraphicssvgitem

I'm new to QT and I'm trying to display only the text items of an SVG file but it only works with the rectangle items.
I use QSvgRenderer and the method setElementId of the class QGraphicsSvgItem.
Does anyone know how to manipulate only text items with their id?

> 

```
item = new QGraphicsSvgItem(QString( "SVG_Logo.svg"));
   
    renderer = new QSvgRenderer(QLatin1String("SVG Logo Highlights.svg"));

    total = new QGraphicsSvgItem();


    bool exist_rect = renderer->elementExists(QString("rect1055"));


    bool valid = renderer->isValid();

    std::cout<<"exist_rect:"<<exist_rect<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"valid:"<<valid<<std::endl;

    total->setSharedRenderer(renderer);

    /* Work with rectangle but not text !!*/
    total->setElementId(QLatin1String("rect1055"));
```

Comment: Do you mean, you want to load the XML as DOM,  remove everything except text items, and then use that modified XML for display?

Comment: What I want is to display only the text object of an SVG file, once loaded in memory. I want to display this text in a QGraphicsScene for example or another container.
What I find strange is that the text is displayed when I load the complete SVG in a QGraphicsScene.

Comment: And when I test if the element exists with 'elementExists(QString("text315"))' it returns true

Comment: @hyde,
Using SVG as DOM is a very good idea.
It offers a lot more possibilities, thanks for letting me know about this method.
I was able to solve my problem.